# Compare part of the string with another string from STDLB

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if there is a function like `preg_match` in PHP where I can find or match a string with another string.

```
   //In Array `word`       // in array `part`
   "Backdoor",        0        "mark"         3 (matches "Market")
   "DVD",             1        "of"           2 (matches "Get off")
   "Get off",         2        ""            -1 (no match)
   "Market",          3        "VD"           1 (matches "DVD")
```

I'm thinking that if there is a function that can match just part of the string it would be great, but as far as I know there is only `strcmp` but that will only compare if is match or not for the whole string in which my case will always be false.

Comment: @Hybride I mean in C++ not in `PHP` in `PHP` I know about that.

Comment: @Hybride: Ali wants an equevalent for preg_match of php in C++

Comment: accept best answer between offered answer and make the Tick green. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::strstr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr).  It doesn't do regexes, but it does do simple string-in-string matching.

```
const char *foo = "Quick brown fox";
const char *bar = "brown";

printf("%d\n", strstr(foo, bar) - foo);  // Displays "6"
```

And as you're in C++, there's also [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find):

```
std::string foo = "Quick brown fox";
std::string bar = "brown";

std::cout << foo.find(bar) << "\n";   // Displays "6"
```

Comment: any example of how to implement that in my case? or I still need to write more codes to use them?

Comment: why it is returning `6` in the above example you gave? Can you please explain a bit for my understanding?

Comment: Because `"brown"` starts at character #6 in `"Quick brown fox"`.

Comment: I have tried something like this, not sure if it is wrong but the result is a very big number `strstr(phrase[1], word) - phrase[1];`

Comment: @Ali: Take a look at the documentation I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `std::string::find()`

also you can use `std::strstr()`

---

as another alternative you can implement this function using dynamic programming or backtrack method (Dynamic Programming has higher performance).

Naturally, i know this question is not an algorithmic problem, but i think this answer can be useful

Comment: I'm trying to see how can I implement this to my question or I will need to do the compare myself....

Comment: what do you mean? you choose my last offered alternative (self implementation)?

Comment: Well what I'm trying to say is that. Will I accomplish what I'm trying to do as per my question with the function you provide? or I will still need to write more codes to get my result ?

Comment: you can use example of Oli, or ask me to give you DP solution.

Comment: I have tried something like this, not sure if it is wrong but the result is a very big number strstr(phrase[1], word) - phrase[1];