# Compare part of the string

Tags: c++, logic

Okay so here is what I'm trying to accomplish.

First of all below table is just an example of what I created, in my assignment I'm not suppose to know any of these. Which means I don't know what they will pass and what is the length of each string.

I'm trying to accomplish one task is to get to be able to compare part of the string

```
   //In Array `phrase`       // in array `word`
   "Backdoor",        0        "mark"         3 (matches "Market")
   "DVD",             1        "of"           2 (matches "Get off")
   "Get off",         2        ""            -1 (no match)
   "Market",          3        "VD"           1 (matches "DVD")
```

So as you can see from the above codes from the left hand side is the set of array which I store them in my class and they have upto 10 words

Here is the class definition.

```
class data
{
    char phrase[10][40];
public:
    int match(const char word[ ]);
};
```

so I'm using member function to access this private data.

```
int data::match(const char word[ ])
{
    int n,
    const int wordLength = strlen(word);

    for (n=0 ; n <= 10; n++)
    {
        if (strncmp (phrase[n],word,wordLength) == 0)
        {
            return n;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The above code that I'm trying to make it work is that it should match and and return if it found the match by returning the index `n` if not found should always return `-1`.

What happen now is always return `10`.

Comment: If your assignment allows it, you could use `std::string` with `std::string::find`, or `std::includes` in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: @chris As long as I know my professor didn't restrict us to use any other library, but she never tough us any of those and I don't really understand the way to use it that is why.

Comment: @Jack I hope I can implement that one.

Comment: @Ali, well with `find`, all you'd need is something like `std::string s = "Market"; if (s.find ("Mark") != std::string::npos)...` and with `includes` you can use beginning and one-past-end addresses for the ranges required. Using `std::string` in the first place would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @chris the thing is that all the string that is coming from `int main` I'm not suppose to know what exactly is the data in the array that is pay from the main, so what happen is that they will just pass array call `word` which will only contain part of it and I have to compare from `phrase` which is 2D array and is upto 10 words so I have to look through it and if found return the index of that array.

Comment: How is this different to your last question?  [Compare part of the string with another string from STDLB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971681/compare-part-of-the-string-with-another-string-from-stdlb)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I couldn't get that one work and I don't know I'm trying and I don't know what should I do now :/

Comment: @Jack your solution is good, but I think I'm missing something and is always return `-1`

Comment: @Ali In regards to your previous question and this one. If you couldn't get the previous solution to work post the code to what you tried and a description to get additional help. Take one lesson and turn it into two then three and so on. Eventually you'll have your problem solved and hopefully have a better understanding of the solution. Who knows you may even discover a better approach.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious  well is not solve yet, but I'm trying Jack solution and it is weird that is always return -1. And I'm very sorry for doing that which I'm not suppose to.

Comment: @ali I'll whip of up answer for ya

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thanks!, In the meanwhile I'm also trying to test it with some other method, but really I really want to bang my head on the wall now :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there but your code is incomplete so I''m shootin in the dark on a few things.

You may have one too many variables representing an index. Unless `n` and `i` are different you should only use one. Also try to use more descriptive names, `pos` seems to represent the length of the text you are searching.

```
for (n=0 ; n <= searchLength ; n++)
```

Since the length of `word` never changes you don't need to call `strlen` every time. Create a variable to store the length in before the `for` loop.

```
const int wordLength = strlen(word);
```

I'm assuming the text you are searching is stored in a `char` array. This means you'll need to pass a pointer to the first element stored at `n`.

```
if (strncmp (&phrase[n],word,wordLength) == 0)
```

In the end you have something that looks like the following:

```
char word[256] = "there";
char phrase[256] = "hello there hippie!";

const int wordLength = strlen(word);    
const int searchLength = strlen(phrase);

for (int n = 0; n <= searchLength; n++)
{
    // or phrase + n
    if (strncmp(&phrase[n], word, wordLength) == 0)
    {
        return n;
    }
}

return -1;
```

Note: The final example is now complete to the point of returning a match.

Comment: It makes a lots of sense here to me, I'm trying it now and will give you a quick feedback.

Comment: @CaptainOblious, I'm really sorry to disturb you a lots here, but now when I tried it first I'm getting this error. `segment.cpp:47: error: cannot convert 'char (*)[40]' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strncmp(const char*, const char*, size_t)'` so I'm assuming and removed the `&` from `phrase` and it compiles, but it returns `10` which is like nothing found (the max `SearchLength is `10`)

Comment: And actually the `wordLength` is not always the same number as you can see from my original post that `words` can be empty sometime or it can be upto `4` or less.

Comment: Oh, sorry and I forgot to mention that `phrase` is a char array, but that is from the private section of the class. Not sure if it will make any different.

Comment: @ali like I said I was flying blind. You might want to edit your question and replace your original code with your new endeavor. Make sure to reduce it to the smallest amount code of necessary to compile (and fail only on that line of course). I'll update my answer to reflect the changes in your question.

Comment: @CaptianOblious, Well the thing is that all above codes that we are using is the same you provide. I mean I don't have more than that. :(

Comment: @ali Start by including the declarations of `phrase` and `word` (e.g. char phrase[256];).

Comment: @CaptainOblious, I have modified the original qurstion. I hope this is better now?

Comment: @Ali NM. The example should be complete enough to get you to the next step

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12361/discussion-between-captain-obvlious-and-ali)

Answer (score 0):

I'm puzzled about your problem. There are some cases unclear. For eaxmple

```
abcdefg --- abcde     Match "abcde"?
```

how many words match? any other examples,

```
abcdefg --- dcb     Match "c"?
```

and

```
abcdefg --- aoodeoofoo     Match "a" or "adef"?
```

if you want to find the first matched word, it's OK and very simple. But if you are to find the longest and discontinuous string, it is a big question. I think you should have a research about LCS problem (Longest Common Subsequence)

Comment: well it is like `preg_match` if they are trying to look for a word like `DVD` and if in my array I have something like `Where is my DVD` it will match another example like `Hello` and if in the string I have like `Hey Hello How Are you` it will also match. basically all the data is store in 2D array (10 words upto 40 characters) something like `array[10][40];`

Comment: it is like exact match, if they send me string like `aoodeoofoo` like your example above and in my string I have like `abcdef` or even the whole `a-z` that is not consider as matched.

Comment: I think for the moment Ali would be happy to get something that returns a match.

Comment: well, if there are "Get off" and "offline" in phrase, and "of" in word, which one will be matched?

Comment: then no match. If `word` have the word `off` and in my `phrase` have `offline` it will match, but if they looking for `Off` then no match because it is case sensitive as well.